# "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'" to sysadmin user in SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm seeing some odd behaviour with SQL Server 2012 Express Edition, where a sysadmin user does not have permission to create databases.

The evolution of this installation has been somewhat trying:

- Host machine initialised
- SQL Server 2012 Express Edition installed on Virtual Machine
- Host machine renamed and joined to the domain
- Domain rebuilt and machine re-joined to the domain

The sysadmin user that is suffering the problems is a domain user.  The user appears in the Security -> Logins node in SSMS, and the sysadmin box is checked on the user's "Server Roles" properties.  However, the sysadmin properties don't appear to have "taken": when I log into SSMS as this user, I don't see ~80% of the users configured on this server, and the `CREATE DATABASE` permissions are denied.  There are probably other symptoms hiding as well.

I have read [this related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/172686/permission-denied-when-creating-database-in-sql-server-2008-express), and I do not believe I am suffering the same problem: the solution proposed in that question is to make the problematic user a sysadmin, which I have already done.

Answer (score 1):

If you're relying on the builtin "Administrators" group membership to grant "sa" rights to a use be sure you're running SQL Management Studio elevated, otherwise your user isn't an "Administrator" and, ergo, won't have "sa" rights either.

Comment: The sysadmin server role has been applied to the user identity directly via SSMS.

Comment: It was worth a shot. I'll leave the answer here because it could apply to other people who might come looking, but it's not The Right Answer(tm) for you.